# IP Lookup Table in Memory C

Tags: c, packet, lookup-tables, libpcap

I'm currently experimenting with libpcap and various C applications and trying to do accomplish the following. Upon program initialization, I'd like to load IPs from a file and store them in memory. When I receive some packet details for processing, I'd like to compare an IP with the set of IP's loaded into memory.

What's the best way/data struct to implement this in C? I need to accommodate a list growth and efficient matching, so I feel like a simple lookup array would be a wrong solution. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolutely least amount of work, for really-decent performance, would probably be to just use an array of `uint32_t`.

When loading your data, throw each IP into the array, using `realloc()` to grow it as necessary. Remember to use a sane growth pattern, doubling the allocated length each time it runs out is common and would probably work nicely.

After load, sort the array using a simple `http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort` call.

Then you can search the array quickly using `bsearch()`.

Since this uses only standard functions, it will be very small code-wise, and thus easy to understand and quick to write. No dependencies, and no time spent either chasing down sane libraries, or writing your own higher-level data structures. But since it uses binary search, it will be pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

Well, presumably you won't ever be removing IPs at runtime, just adding. If the list doesn't get huge, there would really be no big gain in sorting it.

Given those two facts, I'd probably just chuck them all in a (generously-sized) array and do linear searches when required. Keep track of where the end of data in the array is, and it will be a trivial matter to add new entries there.

If that is really too slow, you could develop a hash table. It would need to be tweaked based on the typical contents of your IP map to avoid collisions of course (and developed and debugged, as C doesn't have hashes in the standard). Bit of a PITA, but should be doable.

I wouldn't bother with anything in-between (presumably using binary searches for lookups). If you are that desperate for speed, you might as well go all the way.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the number if IP addresses you're likely to have in your table.

For a small number, a balanced binary tree (e.g., AVL tree) should work reasonably well. It has a fair amount of overhead (2 pointers per node) but as long as the number of nodes is small, it's probably not much of an issue (unless you're targeting a system with constrained memory). You could also use a hybrid where a single node stores up to N IP addresses in an array. With semi-careful selection of N, this can reduce  pointer overhead, and improve cache usage.

If you're likely to have more than 10K or so, it would probably be worth considering using a trie instead.

If you're likely to have a *really* large number, you might consider using a simple bitset, one bit per IP address.

Edit: I should add that it can also depend on the frequency of insertions/deletions compared to lookups. One hybrid structure I've found useful in *many* situations is to start with a main array that's sorted, then as items are added, keep them in a separate array that's not sorted. When/if the secondary array gets too big, you sort it and merge with the main array.

Comment: Of all your suggestions, I like the last one (bitset) the best.